# Wordpress looping issue

Tags: php, html, loops, wordpress

On the home page of my site I want the latest post to be the biggest then the older posts to be smaller and below it. See image 
[image]

I have created a wordpress loop which partly does the job, Ive zoomed out so you can get a clearer view. 
[image]

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>

  <section class="latest-blog">
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>

<?php $i = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- Post Title -->
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <!-- /Post Title -->
    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <br class="clear">

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

   </article>
 </section>

<section class="archive">
<?php if(++$i === 1):  ?>
<?php endif; ?>      

<?php endwhile; ?>
</section>    

<?php endif; ?>
```

What seems to be happening is each old post gets given the section archive where as I want all old posts to be inside the section archive as articles.

Comment: That makes sense, because you're dropping the `<section class="archive">` right _inside_ the loop. Can you define what "all old posts" means? Either way, you'll need to run 2 loops, one for whatever isn't an "old post", and one for "all old posts".

Comment: Yup, what I want to happen is when a new post is posted what ever was the new post to be dropped down below as is the first image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I don't think you need multiple loops, rather I think you could just use a "special" case in your loop to handle the first most recent post, but then treat all the older posts normally (it looks like you're trying to do it the other way round?).

How about this:

```
  <?php 
  $firstPost = true; 
  query_posts('showposts=5');
  while (have_posts()) {
     the_post();
     if ($firstPost) {
       ?>
         <section class="latest-blog">
            my_article();
         </section><!-- /latest-blog -->

         <section class="archive">

     <?php 
       $firstPost = false;
     } // end of if(firstPost)
     ?>

     my_article();

   <?php
   } // end of the loop
   ?>

</section><!-- /archive -->

<?php
function my_article() {
   ?>
   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
      <!-- Post Title -->
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
      <!-- /Post Title -->
      <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
      <br class="clear"> 
      <?php edit_post_link(); ?>  
   </article>
   <?php
}
?>
```

If from a *data* point of view, the posts are all the same, there's no real reason I can think of to execute separate queries to retrieve them.  Just *present* the first one differently. Doing so reduces your code which means less places for errors, and reduces DB overhead which means a better performing site.

Also note, the [codex for `query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) suggests this is not an efficient method to do what you're doing.  So once you get this working as is, you might want to investigate the WP recommended approaches of using the `pre_get_posts` action, although that might not be applicable/appropriate in the case where this is a "page".

Comment: If I was to do it this way how would I get it to display more than just the first post? <?php query_posts('showposts=10'); ?> Doesnt work

Comment: You'd need to add your code for however you want your "archive" posts displayed, where I've added "// your archive level posts here". Gimme five and I'll populate it with the basics for you to tweak, if you like?

Comment: Thank you. Im new to this PHP and WordPress stuff so that would be a big help.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 done. Also moved common code to emmit an article into a function. But if you want to handle the guts of an archive article different to the guts of the most recent article, you'd need to move that code from inside the function, to back where the function is called, so that you can do it differently in each case. Or, if this just doesn't work because the post info is out of scope inside the my_article function (it may be...) then as per above, move the code from that function and back into the loop. Sorry, on an iPad so hard to test for you.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 Thanks for the accept, I appreciate it.  I'm interested to know, did the `my_article()` function work for you, or was there a scope problem with the query? (or did you just prefer to emit the article "in line" rather than from a function?).

Answer (score 1):

Break you code into 2 loops.

**First loop for the featured post:**

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=1'); ?>
<section class="latest-blog">
<?php $i = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- Post Title -->
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <!-- /Post Title -->
    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <br class="clear">

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

   </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</section>
```

**And a second loop for the rest of the posts:**

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&offset=1'); ?>
<section class="archive">
<?php $i = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- Post Title -->
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <!-- /Post Title -->
    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <br class="clear">

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

   </article>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
</section>
```

You will notice that we use offset=1 in the query to offset the first post from the second loop (so it doesn't appear twice).

Your final code will look something like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=1'); ?>
<section class="latest-blog">
<?php $i = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- Post Title -->
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <!-- /Post Title -->
    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <br class="clear">

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

   </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</section>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&offset=1'); ?>
<section class="archive">
<?php $i = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- Post Title -->
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <!-- /Post Title -->
    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

        <br class="clear">

    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

   </article>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the recommendation to break the query into two parts. This adds code overhead (maintenance issue) and DB overhead (performance issue), and is not necessary as we can easily differentiate the first row of a resultset from the latter ones in PHP. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sepster - Their won't be any significant performance issue (if any, it's extremely small for the results).  The reason you use 2 queries is because it simplifies the code, separates two different objectives and allows for more flexibility.  It would also be less clean trying to combine it into one query, as the first post has it's own wrapper, and the rest of the posts of their own wrapper.  You would have to include half of the wrapper within the loop, wrapped in an if statement.  The 2 loop approach is correct for his objective.

Comment: Negligible * n hits * reuse similar pattern on multiple pages = poorly performing site. We don't write SQL statements to select 1 row at a time, when we need all 5 rows. So why is it ok to ask WP to do that on our behalf?  A single line 'if ($isFirstPost) {' is "cleaner" IMO than repeating _boilerplate_ code, and code objective is pretty self explanatory. Only need to include the first half of the wrapper at the end of that if block, which is still logically above the wrapped content. There's no "correct".. This is subjective. There is, however "accepted" :-)

Comment: Hey there, just wanted to clarify that my comment re "accepted" was my acknowledgement/concession that OP had accepted your answer not mine.  But now in the context of OP switching acceptance to my answer since, made that comment look like I was being smug - which I was not ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run 2 loops, one for the main posts, and one for the archived posts. You can't just put a counter in the middle and hope that the HTML will magically format itself properly.

Something like this *might* work.

```
<section class="latest-blog">
  <?php query_posts('showposts=1'); ?>

  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <!-- Post Title -->
      <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      </h1>
      <!-- /Post Title -->
      <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>

      <br class="clear">

      <?php edit_post_link(); ?>

    </article>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</section>

<section class="archive">
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  <?php query_posts('showposts=5&offset=1'); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php // code for "archived" post ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

best thing to do is create 2 separate loops,

top loop brings back only 1 post!
the bottom loop returns the other 4

```
// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>    
</div>
<div class="subTop">
<?php
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=4' );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>   
</div>
```

hopefully this helps

M

Comment: Why is this the "best"? What's the benefit of two separate queries? Your second query will include the first queries result anyway, won't it? Or does WP keep track that the current page has already retrieved the first post?

Comment: hi likeChristan has pointed out in his code, you can add the offset argument to the wp query to offset the posts by 1 ie: 'showposts=4&offset=1', this will make it easier, in the long run to manage, Run 1 query to bring back your main first post, this you can style as you like, then run the offset query 2nd, to produce the next set of posts, which dosnt include the 1st post, then this, you can style without causing too much of a headache will trying to separate your first post from the remaining posts,

Comment: :-) I get the sentiment of doing it this way, but I just don't see the task of determining which iteration of a loop we're in, as a headache worthy of causing an unnecessary performance impact and repetition of code.

Comment: lol, don't know why the down vote!! this method is the best in my opinion, if you think you can provide something better? lets see it! and as for the "causing an unnecessary performance impact and repetition of code" if you think this is repetition or degrades performance, you would be wrong, this would load faster than trying to cut up your 1 and only loop, with specific conditions to parse what your wanting to do, 2 loops would be far better and easier to work with!

Comment: That it's the best in your opinion doesn't make it the best. I _have_ provided an answer, that _is_ better at least in the opinion of our peers. Your assertion - that executing a second DB query (with associated connection/transmission overhead, and potentially over a network link to another server) will occur faster than a CPU can handle a single expressionless branch within a five iteration loop - is wrong. Granted the difference is negligible for a single page load, but for many hits it may become noticeable. Repeating code is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).